# Item list container problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to arrange the list in such a way that the items only allow to grow the container from the bottom and make scroll bar appear.

```
CODE : https://codepen.io/Redd_1/pen/qBZWJQG
```

Comment: Please give us your code, if possible in a snippet. Otherwise we cannot answer your question in a qualified way.

Comment: Here is the codepen  https://codepen.io/Redd_1/pen/LYNPJMm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple set `height` on `ul` and set `overflow-y: auto` to make sure that newly added items are staying within the ul and not moving the whole container.

**Demo**

```js
//Add item to list
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
var itemList = document.getElementById('items');

form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

function addItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //User input
  var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

  document.getElementById('item').value = ''

  if (newItem == '') {
    alert('Please enter some value.')
  } else {
    //Adding values to the list
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'list-group-item';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));


    //Add a delete button
    var deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
    deletebtn.className = 'btn';
    deletebtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

    //Append button and li to the ul
    li.appendChild(deletebtn);
    itemList.appendChild(li);
  }

}


//Remove item from list
itemList.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function removeItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the item?')) {
      var li = e.target.parentElement;
      itemList.removeChild(li);
    }
  }
}

//Search items
var filter = document.getElementById('filter');

filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);

function filterItems(e) {
  var text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  var items = itemList.getElementsByTagName('li');

  Array.from(items).forEach(function(item) {
    var itemName = item.firstChild.textContent;
    if (itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10em;
}

.list-group-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.sbtn {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.sbtn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  float: right;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="itemApp.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <header>
    <h1>Item lister</h1>
    <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search items..." id="filter">
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <h3>Add items</h3>
    <form id="addForm" name="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="item" name="textField">
      <input type="submit" class="sbtn" value="submit">
    </form>

    <h3>Items</h3>
    <ul id="items">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class=btn>X</button> </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class=btn>X</button> </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class=btn>X</button> </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class=btn>X</button> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="itemApp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```